# Remove QWidgets from QLayout?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt5.4, qlayout, qvboxlayout

I fill my `QVBoxLayout` dynamically with `QWidget` objects I create during runtime. I would like to remove them as well during runtime, but how?

I could remove the widgets one by one:

```
void QLayout::removeWidget(QWidget * widget)
```

Can I somehow iterate through the layout?

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. What is your problem with `removeWidget` ?

Comment: @Jérôme I put multiple QWidgets into that Layout adn I do not remeber them. I want to remove them all.

Answer (score 6):

All roads lead to Rome ;)

The [Qt documentation of `QLayout::takeAt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt) states:

> The following code fragment shows a safe way to remove all items from
>   a layout:
>
> ```
> QLayoutItem *child;
> while ((child = layout->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
>     ...
>     delete child;
> }
> ```

To also delete the managed widget, you need to add just one line:

```
QLayoutItem *child;
while ((child = layout->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
    ...
    delete child->widget();
    delete child;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a `count` method that returns the number of stored widgets, and a `itemAt()` method that, given an index, it returns the pointer to relative stored widget. You can retrieve all pointers and then remove them. You should first retrieve all pointers, because if you remove one while counting then the number of stored widgets changes during iterations.

`itemAt()` retrieve a `QLayoutItem` with a `widget` method that retrieves the widget itself.

```
while (layout->count() != 0) {
  QLayoutItem *item = layout->itemAt(0);
  layout->removeWidget(item->widget());
}
```